# How to set daylight saving to off in php

Tags: php, datetime, timezone, dst

I've got this line of code which set daylight saving "On" what would be the proper way to set it to "off"

```
// is daylight saving On?
$rcmail_config['dst_active'] = (bool)date('I');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date('I')` (that's a capital letter i) returns 1 when the [current default time zone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) is in DST.

If it's returning 1 instead of 0 *and the timezone in question is not in DST*, either the timezone you've picked is incorrect *or* the time zone data it uses is out of date.

If you can, please try using a [DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with a [DateTimeZone object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)  that has been [set to the proper time zone](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.settimezone.php).  A [`format('I')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) call on the resulting object *should* be correct.  If it isn't, then your time zone data is out of date.  This is sometimes done at the server level.  Please ensure that the server's time zone database is up to date.  PHP sometimes includes it's own time zone data file, so you may need to actually update PHP instead.

Comment: @Oudin, please be aware that by hard-coding that value, you're going to have a problem later this year when DST changes again.  You **must** fix the underlying problem that is preventing it from working properly, automatically.

Comment: the thing is i don't want it on I want it off by default

Comment: Fair enough -- though you might want to put a comment in the code where you do hard-code it off that you did so intentionally.  Otherwise future-you is going to be really, really upset if you change your mind.  :)

Comment: I have commented it not to that extent but will. The region I'm in does not use daylight saving hence the reason i want it off I was trying to turn it off by default without hard-coding it but could not figure it out

Comment: @Oudin, the fact that your region doesn't have DST, but that the server thinks that it does was my core point.  You really, really should investigate that when you can.

Comment: hmm i would have to contact my host and see if they would be able to turn it off because i don't have access to do so