# correct php timezone list which matches with reality

Tags: php

Following function provides me list of all supported timezone. But problem is the listing is wrong. Please check "America/New_York" it should be -05 but it shows -04. You [can check screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x76gr.png) here. Please give me a solution to get 100% correct timezone listing and i will be able to catch that timezone value to save in my database. so like this function i also need proper format like "America/New_York" from that listing. only to display the timezone list will not work for me coz i have to save it on database.

```
<?php
  function tz_list() {
  $zones_array = array();
  $timestamp = time();
  foreach(timezone_identifiers_list() as $key => $zone) {
    date_default_timezone_set($zone);
    $zones_array[$key]['zone'] = $zone;
    $zones_array[$key]['diff_from_GMT'] = 'UTC/GMT ' . date('P', $timestamp);
  }
  return $zones_array;
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <select class="field" name="time_zone_selector">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Choose TimeZone</option>
        <?php foreach(tz_list() as $t) { ?>
          <option value="<?php print $t['zone'] ?>">
            <?php print $t['zone'].' ('.$t['diff_from_GMT'] . ') ' ?>
          </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: The current new york timezone is -4. It is EDT currently, EST is Oct-Mar (I think, maybe Sept-Mar). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time

Comment: You appear not to have considered Daylight Saving Time.

Comment: as per my computer timezone set its -05 @ new york. How can i get that value from php list?

Comment: @Gekingpoe, your computer is wrong. Unless you can specify what you actually want we can't help you. (It looks like the UTC offset for America/New_York _isn't_ what you actually want.)

Comment: Well that won't be the right time but I guess you can look at this thread, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330983/how-to-set-daylight-saving-to-off-in-php.

Comment: No. i think its about "aylight Saving Time". Tell me how can i get aylight Saving Time formatted timezone?

Comment: @Gekingpoe, UTC-04:00 (Eastern Daylight Time—EDT) is the current offset for New York over the summer while Daylight Saving Time is active. If you check in the winter you'll get an offset of UTC-05:00 (Eastern Standard Time—EST). I'm still not clear on what you actually want, here…

Comment: Yes i need output under (Eastern Standard Time—EST) format? is it possible?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible; are _you_ sure it's what you want? A user in New York (or Toronto, or many other major cities in North America) would be justified in thinking that a dropdown showing "UTC/GMT -05:00" is wrong over the summer (because it is).

Comment: Ok but i want (Eastern Standard Time—EST) format

Comment: whats the proper solution for that actually?

Comment: @Gekingpoe, try using `"EST"` instead if `"America/New_York"`. Or take your difference from a date that falls outside of Daylight Saving Time, like January 1. As a last resort you may have to adjust the difference manually by an hour… I would _**strongly**_ avoid doing that if I were you; time zones are _surprisingly_ complicated. I'd also love to know your use case for doing this. There's a good chance this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).